# web method for sending a file

Tags: java, web-services, file

I have a web service and I would like the client to send a file on server via a web method and then read the file that the client has sent.

The  web method is this :

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getfile")
public void getfile(@WebParam(name = "getfile") DataHandler dh) throws IOException {

    InputStream in = dh.getInputStream();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(in, writer, "UTF-8");
    String theString = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(theString);

}
```

and the client calls the method from here :

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, IOException_Exception{

    SOAPService service = new SOAPService();
    SOAPProxy = service.getGetXMLPort();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\manos\\Downloads\\manos.txt");
   FileDataSource fd = new FileDataSource(file);
   DataHandler datahandler = new DataHandler(fd);
   InputStream in = datahandler.getInputStream();
   byte [] array = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
   SOAPProxy.getfile(array);


}
```

but I am getting a NullPointerException in line SOAPProxy.getfile(array);

**this is the error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
at $Proxy32.getfile(Unknown Source)
at com.mantsap.getxmlclient.SOAPClient.main(SOAPClient.java:25)
```

Java Result: 1

**the length of the array is 8**! i made a system.out to be sure.

The file manos is just a text file.

Thanks in Advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

There could be any of the below reasons..

1. You may not be sending the port or the profile.
2. The service itself might be returning a null so that the exception comes up.

Comment: it s something weird with the call of the web method. The parameter of the method is a Datahandler and when i call the method netbeans ask for a byte [] as parameter. Do you have any idea about it???